# how can I take the results and pass it through dictionary in ansible

Tags: ansible

```
---
#test loop with_item
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no

  pre_tasks:

  - name: delete /tmp/test.txt
    file:
      path: /tmp/test.txt
      state: absent

  tasks:

  - name: set facts ad_users
    set_fact:
      ad_users: []

  - name: set facts ad_users, need to populate ad_results <--------------------
    set_fact:
      ad_results: {}

  - name: Recursively find /home
    find:
      paths: /home
      file_type: directory
    register: find_var

  - name: Append string to list
    set_fact:
      ad_users: "{{ ad_users + [ item.path| basename ] }}"
    loop: "{{ find_var.files }}"

  - debug: var=ad_users

  - name: Get full username from Active Directory
    shell: "/bin/adquery user '{{ item }}'| awk -F: '{print $5}'"
    register: ad_fullname
    loop: "{{ ad_users }}"

  - name: debug ad_fullname
    debug:
      var: ad_fullname.results
```

**Here is the result of fullname.results from debug**

```
TASK [debug ad_fullname] **************************************************************
ok: [centos-test] => {
    "ad_fullname.results": [
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_label": "apps",
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "/bin/adquery user 'apps'| awk -F: '{print $5}'",
            "delta": "0:00:00.022701",
            "end": "2019-06-28 00:09:02.713134",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/bin/adquery user 'apps'| awk -F: '{print $5}'",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "apps",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2019-06-28 00:09:02.690433",
            "stderr": "apps is not a zone user",
            "stderr_lines": [
                "apps is not a zone user"
            ],
            "stdout": "",
            "stdout_lines": []
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_label": "linuxtest",
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "/bin/adquery user 'linuxtest'| awk -F: '{print $5}'",
            "delta": "0:00:00.017644",
            "end": "2019-06-28 00:09:02.841312",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/bin/adquery user 'linuxtest'| awk -F: '{print $5}'",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "linuxtest",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2019-06-28 00:09:02.823668",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "linux test",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "linux test"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_label": "linuxtest2",
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "/bin/adquery user 'linuxtest2'| awk -F: '{print $5}'",
            "delta": "0:00:00.017439",
            "end": "2019-06-28 00:09:02.966616",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/bin/adquery user 'linuxtest2'| awk -F: '{print $5}'",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "linuxtest2",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2019-06-28 00:09:02.949177",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "linux test2",
            "stdout_lines": [
                "linux test2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "_ansible_item_label": "cngo",
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "/bin/adquery user 'cngo'| awk -F: '{print $5}'",
            "delta": "0:00:00.022745",
            "end": "2019-06-28 00:09:03.097507",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/bin/adquery user 'cngo'| awk -F: '{print $5}'",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "argv": null,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "cngo",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2019-06-28 00:09:03.074762",
            "stderr": "cngo is not a zone user",
            "stderr_lines": [
                "cngo is not a zone user"
            ],
            "stdout": "",
            "stdout_lines": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I need populate dictionary ad_results with
ad_fullname.results.item:  ad_fullname.results.stdout
when ad_fullname.results.stdout is not define

the problem is
when I try to debug
I keep getting error

```
  - name: debug ad_fullname
    debug:
      var: ad_fullname.results.item
```

I keep getting this error
"ad_fullname.results.item": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

Answer (score 0):

As its name implies, and your example text shows, `.results` is a **list** and thus has no such property `item`; you are looking for:

```
- name: debug ad_fullname
  debug:
    msg: '{{ ad_fullname.results | map(attribute="item") | list }}'
```